# How to bind global variable in app service provider in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Lumen microservices, how do we add global variables that can be accessed by the entire platform.

We can use the app singleton in Laravel as follows:

```
App::singleton('lookup', function() {
    return true;
});
```

Hence, we can use the variable by using syntax `$lookup = app('lookup');`

But the same could be true for lumen.

In the same way, I want to create a global variable in the lumen. This can be used inside of my models.

Answer (score 1):

With the below code, I was able to achieve what I needed after a few tries.

The following code is placed in the `boot()` method of `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
$this->app->singleton('lookup', function () {
    return true;
});
```

I hope others find it useful in the lumen microservices.

Comment: This is very uncommon. In laravel you'd normally use `app()->instance('lookup', true)` to bind a known value to the container as a singleton.

Comment: Here I have added the function because I am querying inside the function.